# Javascript: Convert Array to Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Which is the easiest way to convert this:

```
[{src:"websrv1"}, {dst:"websrv2"}, {dstport:"80"}]
```

to this:

```
{src:"websrv1", dst:"websrv2", dstport:"80"}
```

in order to pass it to AJAX data?

I'm using [VisualSearch](http://documentcloud.github.io/visualsearch/) and it returns an array of Facet model instances which i need to convert into an Object.

Comment: Are the parentheses `(` and `)` supposed to be curly braces `{` and `}`?

Comment: Why are there parenthesis (`()`) in your desired object?

Comment: You can just pass the array, $.ajax accepts arrays as well.

Comment: $.extend.apply({}, [{src:"websrv1"}, {dst:"websrv2"}, {dstport:"80"}])

Comment: Why are people giving jQuery solutions? I don't see any jQuery here, or am I just missing it?

Comment: @cookiemonster: because VisualSearch depends on jQuery, and a one-liner is a lot cleaner than nested loops or custom functions...

Comment: @cookiemonster - And passing an object to "ajax data" generally means jQuery as native XHR only accepts strings.

Comment: @dandavis: Oh OK, that makes sense then. The question should really get tagged properly if that's what OP means.

Comment: @dandavis: FWIW, I like your `$.extend.apply` solution, though I think it'll modify the first object in the array. May not be an issue though.

Comment: @cookiemonster: i just saw Leo's answer and knew a better way than for to apply an array to it... i checked and the first array object is not modified by my code.

Comment: @dandavis: That surprises me that the first object isn't modified. The effective call is going to be `$.extend({src:"websrv1"}, {dst:"websrv2"}, {dstport:"80"})`. Maybe jQuery pays attention to the `this` value? Or maybe I'm just forgetting how it works? Either way, I'd +1 your answer.

Comment: @dandavis: Did a quick test, and the first object is modified. http://jsfiddle.net/R7Wfz/1/ But again, it may not make a difference, though a quick `.concat()` resolves the issue.

Comment: @cookiemonster oops, good eye. i like reduce too.

Comment: @cookiemonster jquery is javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var a = [{src:"websrv1"}, {dst:"websrv2"}, {dstport:"80"}];

 var b = a.reduce(
   function(reduced,next){
      Object.keys(next).forEach(function(key){reduced[key]=next[key];});
      return reduced;
   }
 );

//b should be {src:"websrv1", dst:"websrv2", dstport:"80"}
```

think about the array.reduce function everytime you need to perform these kind of transformations.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: I really just can't figure it out. Although it should work, visualsearch returns only the last Facet model instance on each search.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jquery, try this:

```
var array = [{src:"websrv1"}, {dst:"websrv2"}, {dstport:"80"}]
var arrayObj = {};

for(var i in array) {
    $.extend(arrayObj, array[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.reduce()`.

```
var result = data.reduce(function(obj, item) {
    for (var key in item)
        obj[key] = item[key];
    return obj;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Don't use this!** but just for fun

```
var a = [{src:"websrv1"}, {dst:"websrv2"}, {dstport:"80"}];
var f = a.reduce((c,d) => Object.assign(c,d), {})
```

The tiny drawback is that `a` is mutated with an infinite recursive object but, who cares? it works in one line!

Answer (score -1):

Original answer using only the most basic features of JavaScript:

```js
var input = [{src:"websrv1"}, {dst:"websrv2"}, {dstport:"80"}];

var output = {};
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  for (var n in input[i]) {
    output[n] = input[i][n];
  }
}

console.log(output);
```

---

**UPDATE:** Using newer features of JavaScript, you can do this trivially with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and [spread syntax (`...`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
var input = [{src:"websrv1"}, {dst:"websrv2"}, {dstport:"80"}];

var output = Object.assign({}, ...input);

console.log(output);
```

Also, `Object.assign(...input)` will return the same result, but will modify the first element of the `input` array. As long as you don't mind that side effect, I'd use this simpler version.

Answer (score -1):

My 2cents, very easy to read:

```
var myObj = {};
myArray.forEach(function(obj) {
  var prop = Object.keys(obj)[0];
  myObj[prop] = obj[prop];
})
```